# Symfony2 - AngularJS implementation/usage

Tags: angularjs, symfony, model-view-controller, architecture

I know there have been some posts about this issue, but not one was completed or helpfull.
At the end of this post you will see my questions about this architecture.

I am implementing angularjs/ui in my symfony-application where angular represents the frontend and symfony2 the backend(model,controller,api,routing etc..).

I installed Angular and bootstrap through bower:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.7",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Next i did some decorative stuff using Grunt to keep the folder/file structure nice and clean.

I included nessacary js-files:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>    
<script src="{{ asset('js/angular.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

// This is my file:
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

I included nessacary css-files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />

// This is my file:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" />
```

What i would like do now is:

1. Forget about Twig and use only angularJS/UI
2. Build an desktop-like-app with angularJS/UI
3. Keep MVC-structure in angularjs

Is it possible to create a structure like this in:

app/Resources/Views/ :

```
articles/
articles/app.js
articles/views/
articles/views/view-files...
articles/controllers/
articles/controllers/controller-files...
articles/models/
articles/models/model-files...
```

I know this architecture from ExtJs and i am quite interested if its possible to do this in AngularJS as well.

Any idea´s??

Thanks and Greetings!